# Is praying sometimes just because one is lazy, then he has become a weak Muslim?

Tags: salat

I’m asking this because, I read somewhere in Islamqa saying this:

> If the one who does not pray does not do it because he denies that it is obligatory, even though he is aware that Allah has commanded that prayer be established, then he is a kaafir and an apostate according to the consensus of the ummah. [*islamqa.info*](https://islamqa.info/en/194309)

And I want a prove from Quran that says like this. I know that the Prophet said clearly:

> ”Between a man and shirk and kufr there stands his giving up prayer.”

Sometimes, I don’t feel like I wanna do something, I feel lazy sometimes.

When I moved to Romania from Kuwait due to medical problems, my parents decided to make one way travel. And since I reached grade 11 I had the worst time table ever, I start from 13:00 and we go home late at night, and I go home I feel tired that I don’t want to do anything but to go to my bed and sometimes I feel like I don’t want to do nothing. But also I have my moment when I pray regular. And in school, I don’t have a place for me to pray in private, but in rest I ask God’s forgiveness more than sometimes. Please tell me I haven’t committed the sin of disbelief.

**My question is:** Am I a weak Muslim by doing like this?

If is there any thing that needs to be corrected, please inform me. And tell me what to correct.

Comment: I wonder if this question is on-topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Praying is the second pillar upon which Islam is built.
The prophet said:

> *"That which differentiates us from the disbelievers and hypocrites is our performance of Salat. He who abandons it, becomes a disbeliever."*

Hadith 98 book 9 riyad us salihen.

Allah says in 107:4

> So woe unto those performers of Salat (prayers), who delay their salat from its time.

And in 19:59

> Then, there has succeeded them a posterity who have given up As-Salat (the prayers) [i.e. made their Salat (prayers) to be lost, either by not offering them or by not offering them perfectly or by not offering them in their proper fixed times, etc.] and have followed lusts. So they will be thrown in Hell.

So brother do you see how Salat (prayers) is important?
In school you can pray in any empty class or room, some scholras even said that you can pray while sitting in a transport to home.

Just try to adjust your timetable with the timing of salat. When salat time comes, take a 5-minute break and pray.
And if you go home at the end of the day you should pray what have missed you. What makes salat seem so difficult is merely Satan. At least your heart will feel free from guilt.

Comment: Yeah but, I don’t like to do this in front of others, because they’ll make a video of me and I hate this to happen, it will be like they want to mock me or to make fun of me, because they don’t go outside, some they stay in class a whole day. Does that mean that, even if I have missed the prayers due to laziness, I can recover them at night after Isha?

Comment: If you are convinced that what you do is the right thing, why care about others? anyway, just try to find anywhere with no one around there must be some place where no one can video you. and it is a very great sin to miss salat due to laziness as I quoted in 107:4, of course you can (and you must) recover them after Isha but just think of it. would you prefer to disobey Allah to satisfy people? or ignore people and obey their creator?

Comment: Well, I really want to obey God as much as I can. Thank you very much.

Comment: May Allah guide you and me Insha'llah. Obey Allah and he will love you, and when he loves you he will make everyone love you.